# How to pass mutipal values from controller to HTML

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

My student table is consist of sname and sex, I want to print each record to html. How could I do that?

From controller:

```
$sname = DB::select('select sname from student);
return view('student', ['sname' => foreach $rname->rname]);
```

$sname is an array, how could I pass all of the value?

Blade HTML:

```
<h>List of student</h>
    <h1> {{ $sname }}</h1>
    <h1> {{ $sex }}</h1>
```

How to express for each in both case?
Thank you.

Comment: This code is wrong in many aspects. You should take a closer look at examples in the documentation (both Laravel and PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller:**

```
$students = DB::select('select * from student')->get();
return view('student', compact('students'));
```

**View:**
Shows a vertical list of students.

```
<ul>
@foreach ($students as $student)
    <li>{{ $student->sname }} ({{ $student->sex }})</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

See: [Blade – Control Structures in the Laravel 5.5 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#control-structures).